# Vim doesn't display my echo if it's 2 characters

Tags: echo, vim9

On Vim 9 linux running this code:

```
inoremap <C-n> <C-o>:echo "aa"<CR>
```

doesn't display anything
whereas:

```
inoremap <C-n> <C-o>:echo "aaaa"<CR>
```

displays "aaaa" and `Press ENTER or type command to continue` as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the result of echo is overridden by the `INSERT` status.
I propose to set `cmdheight` to 2.

```
set cmdheight=2
```

To validate the hypothesis you can try to replace `echo` by `echom` and verify if a message has been output using `:messages` command.

Not exactly related but for command mapping in insert mode or visual mode I suggest `<cmd>` modifier:

```
inoremap <c-n> <cmd>echo "aaaa"<CR>
```

No need of `<C-o>` no need of `<C-u>` and no need of `:` among other things.